# Should I always replace if...then...else with a ternary in Swift?

Tags: swift, ternary-operator

If I can replace an `if...then...else` with a ternary, should I do so? Or does it come down to which of the two is the most easy to read and clear?

E.g. change:

```
If condition {
  doSomething
} else {
  doSomethingElse
}
```

to

```
condition ? doSomething : doSomethingElse
```

How about with variable assignments :

```
If condition {
  myProperty += 1
} else {
  myProperty -= 1
}
```

to:

```
myProperty = condition ? myProperty + 1 : myProperty - 1
```

Edit : Not looking for peoples' opinion on which they prefer, but whether or not there is an accepted professional practice to replace if...then...else with a ternary if possible.

Comment: Are you asking what the Grand Ultimate Law of Swift Style, Bless Its Name says, or what we think?

Comment: You already know the answer...

Comment: Personally I'd go with whichever one looks the most pleasing & easy to read; I find the ternary version in my second example a little clunky, but I wasn't sure if there was an 'accepted standard' among professional application programmers (my most-used language doesn't have ternarys. Of if..then..else. Or keywords. Just mnemonics).

Comment: I think this is a valid question. Languages have idiomatic styles, and in this case in particular, there's a very clear answer: No!

Comment: `myProperty += condition ? 1 : -1`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks Leo - mentally slapping myself for not thinking of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since both are valid and there is no difference in performance, the goal is readability.

Use a ternary conditional for a simple inline decision.

For anything that wouldn't be appropriate inline or  more complicated than basic arithmetic, it would probably be more readable to use normal conditional statements

Apple has a great example of this in the Swift 2.2 docs

Examples from Swift 2.2 Apple docs:

```
let contentHeight = 40
let hasHeader = true
let rowHeight = contentHeight + (hasHeader ? 50 : 20)
// rowHeight is equal to 90
```

I would say the above is just as readable as below and much cleaner.

```
let contentHeight = 40
let hasHeader = true
let rowHeight: Int
if hasHeader {
    rowHeight = contentHeight + 50
} else {
    rowHeight = contentHeight + 20
}
// rowHeight is equal to 90
```

Comment: NOTE: Compile times for ternary operator are 90% higher than for an `if else`.  (4s vs 4ms) *this compiler bug https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1577 - Runtime performance difference is non-existent.

Answer (score 1):

No. The ternary operator should only be used to select the value of one of two expressions. Think of it as being appropriate if your arguments are "nouns". For example:

```
let wheels = isTricycle ? 3 : 2
```

In cases that perform actions, or have more complex arguments, use traditional `if` statements.

Apple says as much in the iBook "The Swift Programming Language", providing only these types of examples of the ternary operator, and specifically stating:

> “The ternary conditional operator provides an efficient shorthand for deciding which of two expressions to consider. Use the ternary conditional operator with care, however. Its conciseness can lead to hard-to-read code if overused.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2 Prerelease).” iBooks.

Comment: Accepting Nicholas' answer dues to him getting it in first.